# ESP8266 not working with Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino, esp8266, wifi

I am building a WiFi-controlled servo project using an Arduino Nano clone, an ESP8266 ([ESP01](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08B3VZS4N)), a G9133 3.3 V voltage regulator, and a generic 9g micro servo. I just realized, it looks like the ESP01 is actually an ESP01S. I’m not sure if that changes anything.

I am coding it with the Arduino online code editor. Here is where I got the
[code/tutorial](https://home.et.utwente.nl/slootenvanf/2018/03/17/connect-esp8266-control-blynk/). All the code I used is supposed to do is set up the capability to use AT commands and send the AT+GMR command at the beginning.

Here is what is happening:

- The LED on the ESP01 blinks once or twice on power up, but not again. Not sure if this is bad.
- When sending AT commands, I just get “busy p… ERROR”
- It is, however, able to send the AT+GMR command successfully once at the beginning (which it does in the code), but some of it is messed up.

These are the only baud rate settings I could get results with, shown in the picture of code. There is a picture of the serial monitor as well. I did include pictures of the physical circuit, but I don’t think that’s where the problem is.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that if you have a "programming" socket for ESP-01, you should be able to check how the ESP-01 works independently ... like this one https://www.amazon.nl/ARCELI-ESP8266-Breakout-Programmer-Downloaderadapter-auto-download/dp/B09DYGB6FY/ref=asc_df_B09DYGB6FY/?tag=nlshogostdde-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=572282849220&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=6426811782088206435&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1001360&hvtargid=pla-1457125718594&psc=1

Comment: Yeah, that’s what I’ve been avoiding because I don’t have any money right now. A 14 year old’s budget has not been kind to me. But if I really need one I’ll buy one.

Comment: Ok. If I remember well, note that when ESP-01 boots, it does use a "special" speed of 74400 (?) bps. it is why there is some garbage at the beginning of serial transmission. So, insert a little delay in the "setup" procedure of the Arduino program. To be checked.

Comment: ESP-01S (black, memory bigger) is the same as ESP-01 (blue) except for the memory size.

Comment: Ok, I’ll try that when I get home, I will comment the results.

Comment: Have you tried this https://github.com/JAndrassy/WiFiEspAT. In the examples\tools directory, there is a sketch "CheckFirmware.ino". NB: Serial1 is used on D6 (Rx) & D7(Tx) pins. You can change in the sketch. EE&O.

Comment: Note also that all AT commands do not work ... https://docs.ai-thinker.com/en/esp8266/sdk

Comment: Great! I’ll test it out.